# Separating Page Breaks with DinkToPdf

Tags: pdf-generation, dinktopdf

I have this C# in my Program.cs:

```
    var page = "plain";

    var slnpath = $@"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\..\..\..\..";
    var htmlpath = $@"{slnpath}\HtmlTemplates\{page}.html";
    var pdfpath = $@"{slnpath}\PdfFiles\{page}.pdf";
    var dllpath = $@"{slnpath}\DinkNative64bit\libwkhtmltox.dll";

    var html = new StringBuilder(File.ReadAllText(htmlpath));

    var _converter = new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools());

    var context = new CustomAssemblyLoadContext().LoadUnmanagedLibrary(dllpath);

    var globalSettings = new GlobalSettings
    {
        ColorMode = ColorMode.Color,
        Orientation = Orientation.Portrait,
        PaperSize = PaperKind.A4,
        Margins = new MarginSettings { Top = 10 },
        DocumentTitle = "PDF Report",
        //Out = @"D:\PDFCreator\Employee_Report.pdf"  USE THIS PROPERTY TO SAVE PDF TO A PROVIDED LOCATION
    };

    var objectSettings = new ObjectSettings
    {
        PagesCount = true,
        HtmlContent = html.ToString(),
        //Page = "https://code-maze.com/", USE THIS PROPERTY TO GENERATE PDF CONTENT FROM AN HTML PAGE
        WebSettings = { DefaultEncoding = "utf-8" }, //, UserStyleSheet = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "assets", "styles.css") },
        HeaderSettings = { FontName = "Arial", FontSize = 9, Right = "Page [page] of [toPage]", Line = true },
        FooterSettings = { FontName = "Arial", FontSize = 9, Line = true, Center = "Report Footer" },

    };

    var pdf = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
    {
        GlobalSettings = globalSettings,
        Objects = { objectSettings }
    };

    //_converter.Convert(pdf); IF WE USE Out PROPERTY IN THE GlobalSettings CLASS, THIS IS ENOUGH FOR CONVERSION

    var file = _converter.Convert(pdf);

    File.WriteAllBytes(pdfpath, file);
```

And I have [this HTML file I have](https://github.com/HoraceBury/PdfGenerator/blob/master/ConsoleApp1/HtmlTemplates/plain.html) (too big to paste here).

[The generated PDF is mostly fine](https://github.com/HoraceBury/PdfGenerator/blob/master/ConsoleApp1/PdfFiles/plain.pdf), but on Page 3 the page break is not correct. The larger content buts up against the previous content - I assume because it will not fit into the following page.

How can every DIV with the `page` class be made to begin on a new page?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to add a page break after every page, add this in your 
page class:

```
page-break-after: always;
```

Comment: Thanks - but it is not perfect, as stated in the other post. Hence this post.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve a definite page break after each "page" class? If so, maybe try
     page-break-after: always;

Comment: Incredible! That works perfectly! Thank you :) Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

For those who want to prevent page break in the middle of the table like example below:
[image: Page break in the middle of the table]

Just use css **page-break-inside** with **avoid** value:

```
table {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found: https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/issues/7

CSS:

```
table { 
    page-break-inside: auto;
} 

tr { 
    page-break-inside: avoid; 
    page-break-after: auto;
} 

thead { 
    display: table-header-group;
} 

tfoot { 
    display: table-footer-group;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used "page-break-after: always;" inside div and worked perfectly for me using DinkToPdf

```
 var sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.AppendFormat("<div style='page-break-after: always;'></div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a normal page break into html you can try these two ways.

1. put this css on html page `page-break-after: always;`
2. Or add this div to that place `<div style="display:block; clear:both; page-break-after:auto;"></div>`

If you have long tables in your html then to avoid overlappings with table header after page break use the following css.

```
thead { display: table-header-group }
tfoot { display: table-row-group }
tr { page-break-inside: avoid }
```

Happy Coding